# Esper terminating partitioned context

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I have a steam of `ThingEvent`.

```
create schema ThingEvent {
  thingID int,
  isLast  boolean
}
```

I want to process things with the same `thingID`s together so I created a context.

```
create context ThingContext
  partition by thingID from ThingEvent
```

However, when I get a thing with `isLast` set to `true`, that means we're never going to see a `ThingEvent` with the same `thingID` again. But the context will hang around forever causing a resource leak.

I found that an [overlapping context](http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.0.0-beta3/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#context_def_overlapping) can be terminated.

```
create context ThingContext
  initiated by distinct(thingID) ThingEvent(isLast <> true) as startEvent
  terminated by ThingEvent(thingID = startEvent.thingID, isLast = true);
```

But when I use it, I have to manually filter the events.

```
context ThingContext
  select *
  from ThingEvent(thingID=context.startEvent.thingID)
  output when terminated;
```

When I start using patterns, this becomes way too verbose. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a termination clause for keyed contexts.

There is a programmatic way of termination any context partition, [link to documentation](http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.0.0-beta3/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#api-contextpartitionadmin).

Instead of repeating expressions there is a predefined expression alias "expression alias {}".

## Edit:

This functionality was added in the 7.0.0 release http://www.espertech.com/esper/esper-changehistory/

Comment: You are the man! I'd given up already, this question was a hail marry.